# On a trigonometric summation.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I have a function defined as:

$$C_n(w) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^j (a_k \cos(kw) + b_k \sin(kw)) $$

Now it is stated that: 
$$C_n (0) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r = 2}^n \sum_{k = 1}^{r -1} a_k$$

I don't understand why there is a division by $2$ of $a_0$. Shouldn’t just be $a_0$ without a denominator?

Edit:
Here is theorem 3.1.10, the $a_k$ are present only in the first line of this proof.
[image]

And here is the first step of the proof that I am having troubles with.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Letting $n=1$,

$$C_1(0)=\frac 11\sum_{j=0}^0\sum_{k=0}^j(a_k\cdot 1+b_k\cdot 0)$$
$$=a_0$$

Letting $n=2$,

$$C_2(0)=\frac 12\sum_{j=0}^1\sum_{k=0}^j(a_k\cdot 1+b_k\cdot 0)$$
$$=\frac 12\left[a_0+\left( a_0+a_1 \right)\right]$$
$$=a_0+\frac 12a_1$$

So yes, it should be just $a_0$ without a denominator.

Just where was "it stated that..."?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll update with some images, it's probably just a problem of understanding on my part.

Comment: I have updated.